# Вращение картинки

Tags: разработка-игр, android, java

Никто не подскажет, как сделать вращение изображения на java? Хотел использовать

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle);
canvas.drawBitmap(player, x, y, null);
canvas.restore();
```

но как-то оно не так реагирует. Мне нужно, чтобы изображение вращалось постоянно.

**UPDATE:**

Нашел рабочий пример

```
class Car {
    final Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    final Bitmap image;

    Car(Bitmap sprite) {
        image = sprite;  // Created by BitmapFactory.decodeResource in SurfaceView
    }
    void update() {
        this.transform.preRotate(turnDegrees, width, height);
    }
    void display(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.image, this.transform, null);
    }
}
```

но оно крутится очень стремно, не вокруг своей оси, а вокруг оси черт знает чего)

Comment: что бы постоянно - нужен поток =) смотря какая у тебя задача, если там просто картинка - загрузка - я бы использовал gif-ку =)

Comment: не хочется спрайты использоваться, а в моем случае пишу под андроид, там гифок нету, токо спрайты...

Comment: оу народ! подскажите плиз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если анимация делается для Android, то можно попробовать [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation)

> You can use the view animation system to perform tweened animation on Views. Tween animation calculates the animation with information such as the start point, end point, size, rotation, and other common aspects of an animation.

Вращение холста можно сделать так:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();

m.setTranslate(centerX, centerY);
m.preRotate(angle, width/2, height/2);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, null);
```

Comment: Как заставить крутиться картинку? Этот метод только поворачивает но не анимирует.

Comment: Чтобы плавно повернуть (анимировать) нужно поворачивать на небольшой угол каждые T миллисекунд.